# Why can't I set the property of Jquery and get a undefined answer in Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I am currently developing an electron app using javascript,I want to use JQuery in my electron app,I have added the code as indicated in the tutorial at [ourcodeworld.com](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework). I have also installed the JQuery doing the following `NPM I Jquery --save` I have also added `win.$ = win.jQuery = require('jquery');` To my code however, I am getting a `can not set property 'Jquery' of undefined` error.  How would I go about elminating this error?

```
  const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
const windowStateKeeper = require('electron-window-state');
const Menu = electron.Menu;

let win;


app.on('ready', function() {
    win.$ = win.jQuery = require('jquery');
    win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1000, height: 800,  resizable:false })
    win.loadURL('file://./slider.html')
    console.log();
    const menuTemplate = [
        {
            label: 'Quit',
            click: () => {
                app.quit();
            }
        }
    ];
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
});
```

Comment: have you tried this too ?= <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery-3.0.0.min.js');</script>

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón yes, I have declared it in my code along with the fix that was suggested in the answer and I get this everytime I Load slider.html in the electron app, in my google chrome it loads fine. [Image](https://postimg.org/image/1dwqrkwvh7/)

Comment: take a look at @Suren response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just declared your variable, but have not initialized. Initialize it with an `object` and then you can add properties to it.

```js
let win = {};

win.jQuery = 'Test';
```

Comment: win seems a global object for electron is pre-defined

Comment: he redeclared, yes got reason, quit negative,. SORRY

Comment: @Suren Srapyan This fixes the undefined error, but now the jquery is not loading at all like I told Alvaro, I get this every time in this [image](https://postimg.org/image/1dwqrkwvh7/) and what should load is a jquery gallery slider called amazing slider.  I can open an addtional question for this if necessary

Comment: I think the question context differs from this. You need to create another question

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue for my electron app,

For me the following way it worked.

```html
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
    <script src="./../UIControllers/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./../UIControllers/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```